# Spring authorization for logged in users

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

So I am trying to implement spring authorization. I read the documentation and added the code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/register", "resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

This works as simple. But what I really want is that implement my own authenticated() method. So when `anyRequest().authenticated()` is executed it should basically call my own implemented authenticated() method where I check whether a user is logged in or not. I want something like this below

```
authenticated(){
//I check here if user is present in the session or not
//this means logged in or not
}
```

So what I really need is that to know how to implement `authenticated()` method so that when `anyRequest().authenticated()` is executed my own `authenticated()` method will be called.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the behavior you want for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own AuthenticationManager.  It will be Autowired into your filter chain if you @Component it.